# Google Analytics for Firebase on web apps

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics for Firebase for a [React Native for Web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) app. This is working fine in the browser, but does not work when the app bundle is executed on other platforms (Tizen, webOS, Xbox).

As this is in the end simply a React DOM app (packaged with Webpack), I'm wondering if I need some polyfills to make Google Analytics work on these other platforms, if it won't work at all, or if I did something wrong when integrating Firebase.

The JS console does not show any errors or warnings. I can see requests to Google Analytics from the browser, but these are missing when running the web app on the other platforms.

Here's how I integrate Firebase:

```js
import "firebase/analytics";
import firebase from "firebase/app";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "...",
  authDomain: "...",
  databaseURL: "...",
  projectId: "...",
  storageBucket: "...",
  messagingSenderId: "...",
  appId: "...",
  measurementId: "...",
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
this.firebaseAnalytics = firebase.analytics();

const clientID = "...";

this.firebaseAnalytics.setUserId(clientID);
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Versions used:

```
"firebase": "^8.6.8",
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-native-web": "0.14.0",
```

Comment: This question is pretty old and you probably figured this out by now, but it seems as if the missing support for cookies is the reason why it fails. At least, I see a warning stating this in a webOS app. (Testing on LG device)
I would love to know why Analytics does not work with the local storage, at least as a fallback solution... Did you find any workaround or other way to get some analytics?

Comment: Even though it's only been a year, I honestly don't recall how or if we were able to fix this issue, sorry. I would have expected my past self to have answered this question, if we had found a fix though. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the code of this project anymore.